# Typescript: Multiple brackets field declaration

Tags: typescript

I found this expression in a project:

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
    public field: { [key: number] : string } = something
    ...
}
```

and I don't know what it means. Can anyone explain this and give me a reference, so I can learn this type of declarations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`field` is an object type (because of the `{}`) that has a numeric index signature that returns a string. This means that an object assigned to the field can only have numeric keys and the values in the object must be of type `string`

```
let field: { [key: number]: string };

field = {
    0: "A",
    //"A": "A", // error key is not numeric
    //0: 0, // error value is not a string
} 

let a = field[0] //a is string

field = ["A", "B"] // arrays are valid as well
```

You can read more about it [here](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/index-signatures.html)

Comment: @MateutAlin yes, my bad, fixed :)

Comment: @MateutAlin no, it's just the name of the index parameter , it can be any name you want, `key` and `name` are common choices, but any name will do

Answer (score 3):

```
{ [key: number] : string }
```

is an anonymous/inline type declaration, it translates to:

```
interface Anon {
    [key: number]: string;
}
```

The brackets are declare, that the type of any undeclared additional property in that object has to be of type `number` and the value of that type must be a `string`.

```
{ 1: "foo", 2: "bar" } // valid
{ "1": "foo", "2": "bar" } // invalid
```

http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#index-types-and-string-index-signatures